# Running Bash Script files from java code in ubuntu

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, terminal, processbuilder

I am trying to run a bash script file from java code in ubuntu. But the commands are not running. Following is the bash file(batch.bash) located at /home/uttam/downloads/

```
#!/bin/bash
convert rose.jpg rose.png
```

I have installed imagemagick for image conversion, when I run above command from terminal it works perfectly fine.

Below is the java code in eclipse which calls the bash file -

```
public class imageConvert {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] a = {"/bin/bash", "-c","/home/uttam/Downloads/batch.bash"};
        List cmdAndArgs = Arrays.asList(a);

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAndArgs);
        pb.directory(new File("/home/uttam/Downloads/batch.bash"));
        Process p = null;
        p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();

    }

}
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can tell me what problem is causing the commands to not run.
Is this the folder permission issue or java code syntax issue?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Try using the full path to `convert`

Comment: `downloads/` or `Downloads/`?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Did you do `chmod u+x batch.bash`?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard that's not required as it's being called as `/bin/bash -c file`. Only needs to be readable.

Comment: @arco444 Actually, it *is* required. `-c` doesn't mean ‘execute this file’, it means ‘execute this command’, so the same conditions apply.

Comment: @Biffen True. I stand corrected.

Comment: @user3778220 Why not use [an ImageMagick library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#java)?